# How can policy parameterization be simpler than action-value parameterization in function approximation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

In the second edition of the book "Reinforcement Learning: an introduction" by Sutton and Bato page 323 (Policy gradient chapter) it says that:

"Perhaps the simplest advantage that policy parameterization may have over action-value parameterization is that the policy may be a simpler function to approximate."

Can anyone please explain the reason?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a game on the positive half of the number line, where you start at some integer $k$, and can move down by 1 or up by 1 each turn. The reward function is $f(x)$ for some monotonically decreasing function $f$ which is very hard to model -- for example, $f$ could be the negative cost of the optimal solution to a TSP problem on the first $x$ points in some set.

Then clearly, computing all these rewards and the action-value function is quite difficult. However, the optimal policy is simple: move down by 1 always.

Comment: Can you explain more everything after "-- for example", please?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the traveling salesman problem, then that probably wasn't a helpful example. Just imagine that $f$ is a very hard function to model -- the world is filled with such functions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how about moving down by 1 in the game. What was the goal of the game

Comment: @AliGh the MDP formulation does not require a goal -- usually the problem is considered solved when the reward is maximized. In this case, reward is maximized when you reach $0$, since $f$ is maximized there.

Comment: Actually, it is true when we have the reward function. Otherwise, we need to know the object.

Comment: not sure what point you're trying to make

Comment: Nothing related to the question. Just about your last claim. Thanks

Comment: @AliGh The reward is maximized at 0 because $f$ is monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score -1):

Simple rule, action-value would be a mapping to the discrete function while policy network would be mapping to the continuous field. A continuous function is simpler to approximate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not right. What do you even mean by " action-value would be a mapping to the discrete function "